# C++ Compiler parses source file before header file erratically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

When I change a header file, which contains a template class definition, my compiler (the one that ships with VS2015) first parses the source file where the class is instantiated, and only then the header file. This results in an incorrect binary.

However, if I change the header file again and compile, the parsing order is correct (header first, source after), and the resulting binary does the right job.

The order in which the compiler parses the file can be seen in the Build output window and I have no parallel or multi-processor compilation options enabled.

I can reproduce this with 100% success rate. Am I doing something wrong, is there something I could change?

The code is below.

Class.h

```
template<class T> class Class {
    void foo () {
        WriteToFile("A");
    }
```

Usage.cpp

```
Class* c = new C();
c->foo();
```

Full build/rebuild. Output in file: A.

Step 1:

add the following line to `foo()`: `WriteToFile("B");`
Compile: order of output: Usage.cpp, Class.h
Output in file: A

Step 2:

add to following line to `foo()`: `WriteToFile("C")`;`
Compile: order of output: Class.h, Usage.cpp
Output in file: A B C

Go on until forever, same behavior.

Note: I simply hit F7 to "Build", after a full rebuild it works fine, but it takes a long time.

Comment: You should never see a *.h file compiling - you have set something up wrong. *.h files are #include in *.cpp files; *.cpp files are compiled.

Comment: Your class template definition (`template<class T> Class`) is incomplete. That'll make for fun compiler errors, when included into a compilation unit. Even with the edit (`template<class T> class Class`) it is still incomplete. Please don't post made-up source code, even if you believe it to be trivial.

Comment: the code builds and runns, i just missed it when i typed it here. this is not a compiler error question, but thanks anyway, i have edited

Comment: @Hame "Compile: order of output: Usage.cpp, Class.h " - this is wrong

Comment: @Hame I agree with Richard, it just can't compile in that order, so there is either a stale file or you aren't getting a binary when you think you are.

Comment: Compilation does **not** occur the way you assume. However, it is quite possible that compile caches intermediate output of .h and the dependency check for an incremental fails to realize this is out of date. I've seen Visual Studfio dependency checks occasionally fail since VS 5. --- It might not be worthwhile, but your civic duty nontheless to open a bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio.  Please provide a reproducible (full) minimal sample there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Right-click on the file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Item type. For that specific header file, it was set to C/C++ Compiler. After changing it to C/C++ Header, it worked.

I think it happened because when I add a new file to the solution I right-click on a filter -> Add new item. If the Source file is selected, I didn't bother changing it to Header file, I would just name the file SomeName.h. It seems it makes a difference. Based on this, the .vcxproj will contain a line with you file that begins with either `<ClInclude>` or `<ClCompile>`

Answer (score 0):

Your source files (.cpp) are only compiled and it copies code from included header files(.h) into source file.
  Header files are not compiled independently.

Can you pls copy logs from your Build output window.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is riddled with bugs, if this is an example of you normal code, then anything could be happening.

Like was mentioned above you shouldn't see h files compiling.  If you do then you might have set it to be compiled as a cpp file or something similar.  That is the first place you should be looking.

The H files are added into the CPP files during the preprocessing stage, generating long source files that can be read if you select the compile option to retain them.  Don't know what it is off the top of my head.  If you look at these long files then you will see that Class.h is being added into Usage.cpp at the point the `#include "Class.h"` statement occurs.  Unless you are including an old version of Class.h its difficult to see any way what you are describing could happen.  UNLESS you are using precompiled headers and your class.h file is part of the PCH and you are using a stale PCH file.

If you use rebuild all every time, rather than build(F7) I suspect the problem will disappear.  I suspect that this would be because of a PCH generation issue so check you stdafx.cpp is set to regenerate the PCH.